# How to create TableViewCell with compass like localscope App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

example here :

[image]

See the compass in the right handside of UITableViewCell

Comment: Please show us the code you've written so far.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CLLocationManager` to get your location and heading, then calculate relative direction for each coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

**@kyr** is right, you can calculate direction BY `CLLocationManager`, and about the rotated arows images, These could be static images with round background and arrow on it, everytime you calculate direction, you can rotate the Image by `CGAffinetransform` and `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`.

Answer (score 0):

Use CLLocationManager to get the heading.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {
    CLLocationDirection true = [newHeading trueHeading];
    CLLocationDirection magnetic = [newHeading magneticHeading];
}
```